# Formula to calculate time difference based on match's in other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hoping to get some help. I can do basic formula's ect in excel and often find the ones i need using google but cant find anything for what i want to do.

Please picture below

[image]

I have some conditional formatting in place to highlight which values match between column A and D.

What i want is hopefully a formula that will check columns A and D for matches and then look at the times in columns B and E and calculate the time difference relative to the match it finds and show it in column C.

I'm not even sure this is possible but my knowledge just isnt strong enough in Excel and formula's to try and piece it together.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Are values in columns A and D unique? I mean is it a case that we would have one-to-one match, one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If you are checking to see how long it takes to get from one location to the next, you can use a lookup or match function to find the item in col D, then subtract one time from the next.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with this website. As is, your question isn't specific enough. For example in cell `C2` specifically, do you want to calculate the time difference between `AX02` or `AX12`? Also, your question tags and mentions conditional formatting even though your question has nothing to do with conditional formatting. If you update your question accordingly and take the tour, I (and most other people on this site) would be willing to help.

Comment: Hi Sorry for being vague. Columns A and D are car registrations entering at one point and leaving at another. A is entering and D is exiting. Column B are the times relating to column A and column E is relating to column D. I was hoping there would be a formula that would look at the matches and then check the times and tell me what time difference there is. I've been doing this manually so far but hoping there is a formula. Thanks

Comment: TomJohnRiddle - They should be a 1 to 1 match as they are car registrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one-to-one match, which means that for example plate number PP5862A (from column A) will have only one occurence in column D you can use index/match combo (starting from cell `C2`):

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$100,MATCH($A$2,$D$2:$D$100,0),1)
```

This formula will give you exit time for matching plate number.

For explanation how index/match works please refer to this short article: https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact

There are probably some `VLOOKUP` fans here so alternative is (again starting from cell `C2`):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$1:$E$100,2)
```

I have hardcoded ranges to 100 rows - you should adjust it to your needs.

Comment: TomJohnRiddle - Fantastic.Took your formula and modified it to work.

Comment: This is what i ended up using =iferror(INDEX($E$2:$E$100,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$149,0),1)-B2)

Comment: Happy it works for you! And if answer solves your problem please remember to accept it :)

Comment: @Stuart I have just noticed that you have left $E$100 in index. You should probably change it to $E$149?